# "Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"."

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API using django rest-framework. I can use its post method but when I try to use get method I get the following error

```
{
    "error": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"QuerySet\"."
    ]
}
```

here is my code.

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      file_serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file_serializer.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        print("aaaa")
        query = org_details.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=query, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = org_details
        fields = "__all__"
```

I saw some suggested to use many=true as the parameter for the serializer. as you see, it still gives me the same error. your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change
`serializer = self.serializer_class(data=query, many=True)`
to 
**`serializer = self.serializer_class(query, many=True)`**